# How to count on a group by array_agg in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, array-agg

Here is my SQL:

`SELECT t.uid, array_agg(t.place) FROM tour_tracking t WHERE (orderon::time BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '20:00:00') GROUP BY t.uid;`

Origin result:

`|---------------|----------------------|
|      uid      |         place        |
|---------------|----------------------|
|      a01      |     {hk, hk, jp}     |
|---------------|----------------------|
|      a02      | {jp, jp, jp, jp, uk} |
|---------------|----------------------|`

Now I want to count on each DISTINCT place for every group-by-ed uid.
Hopeful result:

`|---------------|--------------------------------------|
|      uid      |                place                 |
|---------------|--------------------------------------|
|      a01      |  something like this: {hk,2, jp,1}   |
|---------------|--------------------------------------|
|      a02      |              {jp:4, uk:1}            |
|---------------|--------------------------------------|`

I try to combine some `count()` sql query but won't work.., how to do the right query?

PostgreSQL version: 10.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aggregate twice.  Once to get the places and their counts, then again to make the lists...

```
SELECT
  t.uid,
  array_agg(array[t.place, t.row_count])
FROM
(
  SELECT
    uid,
    place,
    COUNT(*)   AS row_count
  FROM
    tour_tracking
  WHERE
    orderon::time BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '20:00:00'
  GROUP BY
    uid,
    place
)
  t
GROUP BY
  t.uid
```

Comment: `array_agg` doesn't take an array as input.

Comment: @eurotrash : Then the docs lie...  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Hmm, fair enough, seems like a change that came after the version I use (9.3), and something I've often wished for.

Comment: Note that I was getting `PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  ARRAY types text and bigint cannot be matched
LINE 118:   array_agg(ARRAY[action_name, row_count])`, so I changed it to `array_agg(array[t.place::varchar, t.row_count])`